# Authenticate jBPM through the Identity gateway

Tags: jboss, identityserver4, keycloak, openid-connect, jbpm

I am using jBPM standalone to create workflows. By default, login is performed using the users.properties file.

I have an Identity server (created in Dot Net IdentityServer4 implementing OpenId) running and I registered a client (Ex: JBPM_CLIENT) and have the details (Scope, SecretKeys, etc..)

[image]

I am trying to redirect the authentication of jBPM through that Identity gateway.

While reading the documentation I thought KeyCloak can be used for this requirement.

But, when I see the KeyCloak GUI and configuration, it looks like KeyCloak something like IdentityServer4 and is useful to create an Identity Server instance.

My doubt is whether I can use KeyCloak as a client to connect to IdentityServer4?

Please suggest me a route.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak can act as an identity broker and it supports OIDC (OpenID Connect) identity providers. Using that capability, first configure your IdentityServer4 as the OIDC provider on Keycloak. [Keycloak's documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker_oidc) covers these details.

Once that's set, you can configure jBPM to use Keycloak client adapter for [Wildfly](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_jboss_adapter) and then create a suitable Keycloak client under the same realm where you had configured the OIDC identity provider. Details related to that are covered in this [blog](http://blog.athico.com/2016/03/keycloak-sso-integration-into-jbpm-and.html) (outdated though).